# On checkbox click change select box into a textbox with the same ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Wondering if it is possible that when a checkbox is clicked it changes the select box to a textbox with the same id "Wine_name"

Not really clued up when it comes to javascript, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

The reason I need this, when a user is filling out a form, if the selectbox does not have the option they want to select, they can click the check box which will then allow them to manually type in the text they want.

Comment: **ID**'s should be unique and never used for more than one element at a time. I would recommend you think of a different way to link the two elements together. Maybe assign a `class` to them or maybe use a `dataset`

Comment: is there no way of just changing the selectbox input type to text box then? rather than having 2 boxes?

Comment: Why do you need this? If you can specify the purpose, someone might be able to suggest a workaround.

Comment: @31piy have updated the question with the reason

Comment: @JohnMartyn can you give a working example of what you are currently working with? Only the relevant parts. I am not really sure what you mean by turn the selectbox into a text box...

Comment: What about an option in the selectbox called "own value" which when selected lets an input box beneath appear?

Comment: @JohnMartyn -- for your usecase, you can have a hidden form input which will ultimately be used for data. Assign the ID `Wine_name` to this input. Based on the selection of select box, assign the value to the input box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. you can do it.. just keep in min that you have to disable the hidden input so that it wont be processed when the form is submited.

Have a look at the code that i've come up to do it.

I'm not sure it you really need the same 'id' attribute, if you're just sending a form and processing the result on the server side, you can 'name' the submitted parameters with the 'name' attribute. So that you can freely use different ids on the view side without changing the backend to conditionally verify it.

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector("#custom_value");
var select = document.querySelector("#selection");
var altSelect = document.querySelector("#selection_alt");

checkbox.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  select.classList.toggle('hidden');
  select.disabled = !select.disabled;
  
  altSelect.classList.toggle('hidden');
  altSelect.disabled = !altSelect.disabled;
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="custom_value"> Alternative

<br>
<select id="selection" name="selection">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="1">2</option>
  <option value="1">3</option>
  <option value="1">4</option>
  <option value="1">5</option>
</select>

<input type="text" disabled class="hidden" name="selection" id="selection_alt" placeholder="Custom value..">
```